# retrieve data from database what next?

Tags: android, sql, database

ok I just followed an instruction that I should do this to retrieve sql data from database but it just cuts to there so far I have this inside my databasehelper class.

```
 public void getIconResource(String tblName)
     {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

          String getresource = "Select * from " + tblName;

          Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(getresource,null); //null for conditions

         if(cursor.moveToFirst())
         {
             do
             {
                 int resource = cursor.getInt(3);
             }
             while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }
         db.close();
     }
```

So somehow this does is it get all the values of my tables 4th column which contains an int... how do I retrieve the value in my MainActivity and save it in an array of integers?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you have it, the variable `resource` is scoped only to the `while` loop. Even if it wasn't it would constantly get overwritten on each loop iteration.

Instead, you should declare a collection higher up and `Add` each value to it during your `while` loop. You could also redefine your function to return the collection if integers.

```
public List<int> getIconResource(String tblName)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<int> myVals = new List<int>();

    String getresource = "Select * from " + tblName;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(getresource, null); //null for conditions

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            myVals.Add(cursor.getInt(3));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return myVals;
}
```

Also, as a note... string concatenation of a SQL query is a recipe for disaster. Look up SQL Injection and best practices to avoid it before continuing further. It is worth the time to get into good habits early on.

**EDIT / ADDENDUM**

Unless you also limit your result set returned from your table query, you will be getting every record. The function you have here really has no practical use and would likely cause more problems than any benefits it may have. I would suggest, as an example of a more usable function that returns a specific `IconResource` based on the `IconId`:

```
public int getIconResource(int iconId)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String getresource = "select IconResource from IconTable where IconId = ?";
    PreparedStatement pstmnt = db.prepareStatement(getresource);
    pstrmnt.setString(1, iconId);
    ResultSet rset = db.executeQuery();

    int iconResource;

    if (rset.next())
        iconResource = rset.getInt("IconResource");

    db.close();
    return iconResource;
}
```

Of course, the above is making assumptions of your table structure.

Using the above, in your code elsewhere, you would simply call this function with the `IconId` and use the output however needed:

```
int iconResource = getIconResource(5); // returns the IconResource for IconId = 5
```

The above prevents any possible SQL Injection attacks by using a parameterized query and avoiding the use of dynamic concatenated strings sent to your SQL server.

Comment: can you show me how I can use it in my mainactivity... say for example I want to save one data of a column in `int data = //the forth value of the array`

Comment: What do you mean, "one data of a column"? in your example you are accessing column index 3, but since you are not limiting the result set, you will be getting all of the records in your table resulting in a collection of items residing in column index 3. In your situation that would be a list/collection/array of integers. You would access the individual items using their index position in the collection: `int itemZero = getIconResource("myTable")[0];` gets you the first item in the collection. Could you give an example of the table you are working with, including structure and data sample?

Comment: my bad... I put the `myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this)` way way below were I use the `myDB.getIconResource` ...it works well now on your example what I did is on main activity I used `ArrayList<Integer> resource = myDB.getIconResource(tblnumber);` then `int resource1 = resource.get(0); to get the first value and so on. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try out the following code:

```
public List<Integer> getIconResource(String tblName)
     {
         List<Integer> list =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
         list.clear();
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

          String getresource = "Select * from " + tblName;

          Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(getresource,null); //null for conditions

         if(cursor.moveToFirst())
         {
             do
             {
                 int resource = cursor.getInt(3);
                 list.add(resource);
             }
             while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }
         db.close();
         return list;
     }
```

Then call this method in MainActivity and store the List in another Integer type list.

```
databasehelper dbhelper; 
List<Integer> newList = dbhelper.getIconResource("Your tablename");
   fot(int i = 0 ; i< newList.size() ; i++){
    int yourValue = newList(i);
    }
```

Comment: my application stopped running when I tried this method.

Comment: which error are you getting ? Check the log and let me know, I may help.

Answer (score 0):

just add everything in a ArrayList and return the arraylist
simply call the method in your main activty

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getIconResource(String tblName)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

      String getresource = "Select * from " + tblName;

      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(getresource,null); //null for conditions
```

ArrayList data= new ArrayList<>();

```
     if(cursor.moveToFirst())
     {
         do
         {
             int resource = cursor.getInt(3);
            data.add(resource);
         }
         while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }
     db.close();
 }
```

return data;
}

Comment: how do I call this from my MainActivity?